# Meteor - not populating {{each}} even when console says data is there

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Based on the code below, is there any reason why I am not getting the list of `Categories` populated, even though the browser console shows 6 when I type `Categories.find().count()`?

What did I do incorrectly? Here is [my repository on GitHub](https://github.com/claytonzaugg/zauggstudios/tree/master/app).

**categories.js:**

```
Categories = new Mongo.Collection('categories');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Categories.allow({
        insert: function(userId, doc) {
            return true;
        },

        update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
            return true;
        },

        remove: function(userId, doc) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

**home_controller.js:**

```
HomeController = RouteController.extend({
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.subscribe('categories');
        this.subscribe('photos');
    },
    data: function () {
        console.log(this.params.name);
        Session.set('category', this.params.name);
    },
    action: function () {
        this.render('MasterLayout', {});
    }
}
```

**list_categories.html:**

```
<template name="ListCategories">
    <ul>
        {{#each Categories}}
        <li id="categories"><a class="btn btn-default" href="/{{name}}">{{name}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

**list_categories.js:**

```
Template.ListCategories.helpers({
    Categories: function() {
        return Categories.find();
    }
});
```

**list_photos.html:**

```
<template name="ListPhotos">
    <div id='photos'>
        <div class='page-header'>
            <h1>
        <small>
            {{#if catnotselected}}
                Photos
            {{else}}
                {{category}}  Photos
            {{/if}}
        </small>
      </h1>
        </div>
        <div id='mainContent'>
            {{#each photolist}} {{>photo}} {{else}} {{#if catnotselected}}
            <div class='page-header'>
                <h1><small>Select a category.</small></h1></div>
            {{else}}
            <div class='page-header'>
                <h1><small>No photos in this category.</small></h1></div>
            {{/if}} {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**list_photos.js:**

```
Template.ListPhotos.helpers({
    catnotselected: function() {
        return Session.equals('category', null);
    },
    category: function() {
        return Session.get('category');
    }
});
```

**master_layout.html:**

```
<template name="MasterLayout">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <a class="brand btn" href="/"><img style="height: 40px; width: 135px;" src="img/logo.png" />
                    <p>Photos</p>
                </a>
                <div id="login-button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                    {{> loginButtons}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 text-center'>
                {{> yield 'categories'}}
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center'>
                {{> yield 'photos'}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**master_layout.js:**

```
Template.MasterLayout.onCreated(function() {
    Session.set('category', null);
});
```

**photos.js:**

```
Photos = new Mongo.Collection('photos');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Photos.allow({
        insert: function(userId, doc) {
            return true;
        },

        update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
            return true;
        },

        remove: function(userId, doc) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

**routes.js:**

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'MasterLayout',
    loadingTemplate: 'Loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'NotFound',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'photos': {
            to: 'ListPhotos'
        },
        'categories': {
            to: 'ListCategories'
        }
    }
});

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    action: 'action',
    where: 'client'
});

Router.route('/:name', {
    name: 'photos',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    action: 'action',
    where: 'client'
});
```

Comment: did you check in the DOM if your categories are loaded (the `li` element), but their name not displayed?

Comment: I did try changing the id to {{_id}} and it's still not working.  The DOM does NOT show the li elements that are supposed to be there, so it's like the {{each}} loop is iterating over nothing, but yet in the console I can access the Categories.

Comment: Could you please provide a repository?

Comment: Here's the repo @MatthiasEckhart https://github.com/claytonzaugg/zauggstudios/tree/master/app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected, rendering the `ListPhotos` and `ListCategories` template fails. That's why there are no corresponding elements in your DOM, even though you can access documents of your `Photos` and `Categories` collection via the console.

Apparently, using `yieldRegions` in the global router config will fail, due to an [iron-router issue](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1163), which requires to call `this.render()` in the route's action.

**routes.js:**

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'MasterLayout',
    loadingTemplate: 'Loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'NotFound',
    yieldRegions: {
        //each yield going to different templates
        'ListPhotos': {
            to: 'photos'
        },
        'ListCategories': {
            to: 'categories'
        }
    }
});

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    action: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    where: 'client'
});

Router.route('/:name', {
    name: 'photos',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    action: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    where: 'client'
});
```

Comment: This fixed my problem!  Thank you very much!